# Is there a way for temp directories to be automatically deleted?

Tags: c#, temp

I am wondering is there is anyway for the OS to delete automatically created temp directories.
I am working with an application in C sharp and I create a directory in the temp directory (I get the address with the GetTempPath()), I put a bunch of files in this temp directory.
The problem is, I want that this temp directory to be deleted (with all its content) when the files are no more used (when exactly, I don't care, after logging out or restarting the OS it would be a good solution) in order not to saturate the memory because each time I open a temp directory I open it with a different (random) name, which is necessary in my case. The directory and files still exist after a few days, I checked, so I guess there is something that needs to be done when creating it in order to tell the OS to delete it.

Would it be possible?
thanks,
Josh

Comment: you can schedule a daily task to clean up the directory. However this goes far beyond the scope of a simple question here, in particular when you don´t provide any own affords and where specifcally you encountered problems.

Comment: You are the master of your own destiny here. Use a Scheduled task, group policy, run on started up, when you start your app, when you feel like it, after you finish with them, ect,ect,ect,ect,ect,ect,ect,ect,ect,ect

Comment: In these scenarios, I tend to name the sub directory in a way I can detect later, and then I simply clean up before I create a new folder. My scenario is local development so this might not be a suitable solution for you.

Comment: I do name it with a random name + some keyword so that I can detect it.

Comment: `when exactly, I don't care,` but that's the answer. The OS can't know when you're done with that file so it can't just delete them when you close their handle. Some applications (eg text editors) store unsaved documents there so they can reopen them if the application crashes or is shut down without saving

Comment: You can use [Path.GetTempFileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.gettempfilename?view=net-5.0) to have .NET create a zero-sized temp file and return the path to you. You can set the `FileInfo.Attribute` of the file to [Temporary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileattributes?view=net-5.0) so data isn't even saved to disk if there's enough cache memory. In the end though, only your application knows when a temporary file should be deleted

Comment: I should have been more specific. I don't care when it's deleted meaning, if i close my app i don"t care anymore because the files are only used once during the process

Comment: Consider Visual Studio Code or Sublime Text for example. Both store store unsaved documents to temporary folders so you can shut them down and get back to the same contents when you open the app again.Which allows developers to open 100s of tabs for quick notes until they no longer know what needs to be saved or not....

Comment: `if i close my app i don"t care anymore because the files are only used once during the process` only you know that. So you should take care to clear the files either on shutdown or startup. You can reduce the size of the files by setting the `Temporary` attribute

Comment: There used to be a way, by using Transactional NTFS, to make changes to a file or folder that were invisible to other processes and could be rolled back if the transaction was cancelled. That works only on NTFS file systems though and can be *very* expensive when applied to multiple files. That's why transactions were never implemented in ReFS (which wasn't that succesful). More importantly, other OSs like Linux and OSX don't have similar features, so .NET Core can't offer the feature directly. You can use the [AlphaFS library](https://github.com/alphaleonis/AlphaFS) in .NET Old

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom.compiler.tempfilecollection.addfile?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_CodeDom_Compiler_TempFileCollection_AddFile_System_String_System_Boolean_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well - one way, would be to check the `Delete temporary files that my apps aren't using` box in settings (windows 10)
[image]

just type in 'storage sense' in the windows search bar.

Also see: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/storage-sense-configuration-for-deleting-temporary/321616d1-e6a7-413a-8246-28f88f5ecc4e